# Django returning incorrect attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to get Django to display a list of links to all records currently in the development database on the home/index page.

My views.py code looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import GvData


def index(request):
    all_geneva_data = GvData.objects.all()
    html = ''

    for data in all_geneva_data:
        url = '/geneva/' +str(GvData.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="' + url + '">title</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I have a few sample records already in my database and I've confirmed by using the shell that each record does have an id and can be located with `model.objects.filter(id='#')`.

This code succeeds in creating links but the link returns a page not found error. Instead of placing the integer value of the record id, what's placed in the URL is:

```
%3Cdjango.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute%20object%20at%200x0452BF10%3E
```

Why am I getting this instead of the int value of `id` cast as a string in the url pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing object model instead of object instance

```
   for data in all_geneva_data:
            url = '/geneva/' +str(data.id) + '/'
```

Comment: This did it. Very clear and concise response. I did not notice that was the case.